# Why isn't my package.json updated by npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm just starting out with npm, and as far as I understand the `npm install` command should automatically update the `package.json` file, but with me it unfortunately doesn't.

I'm on OSX and in a new dir called npmtest I did the following:

```
$ ls  # let's first confirm the folder is empty
$
$ npm init --y
Wrote to /Users/kramer65/Downloads/npmtest/package.json:

{
  "name": "npmtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I then installed underscore:

```
$ npm install underscore
npmtest@1.0.0 /Users/kramer65/Downloads/npmtest
└── underscore@1.8.3

npm WARN npmtest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN npmtest@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

which seems to be installed fine:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 kramer65  staff  102 Oct 18 17:47 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 kramer65  staff  221 Oct 18 17:47 package.json
```

unfortunately `npm list` complains that it's not in the `package.json` file with the `extraneous` flag:

```
$ npm list
npmtest@1.0.0 /Users/kramer65/Downloads/npmtest
└── underscore@1.8.3 extraneous

npm ERR! extraneous: underscore@1.8.3 /Users/kramer65/Downloads/npmtest/node_modules/underscore
```

Which I can confirm:

```
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "npmtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The question is; why isn't it entered in the `package.json` file? Shouldn't that go automatically? What am I doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: `npm install` doesn't update the `package.json` file, `npm install *module name* --save` updates the `json` package.

Comment: @ZombieChowder - Ah, thanks. Can you add that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm install` doesn't update the package.json file, `npm install *module name* --save` updates the `json` package. Hope that helps.

Comment: Slight clarification - NPM v5 does update the package.json without `--save` if you do `npm install modulename`. Your answer is correct for older versions, though.

Comment: @JoeClay yes buuuut in most cases the latest version is never used for development or production. Idk, I just presumed so.

Comment: I think that's a fair assumption, yeah. v4 is still the default in the current LTS version of Node.

Comment: @JoeClay - Thanks for the tip. Since I'm just starting out with Node and npm I simply upgraded to NPM v5 and I'll forget about it for now. Always good to be able to forget about legacy when you're starting out afresh.. :-)

Comment: @kramer65: NPM 5 becomes the default in a few weeks I think (once Node 8 moves to long term support), so you're not too far ahead of everyone else :)